# Xcode - building for arm64 way slower than for intel iPhone simulator architecture

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

I have a relatively big mobile ios app project and am building it on an M1 MacBook Pro. It's a mixed Swift and Obj-C prject.

When I am building it via Xcode for the "Intel Iphone Simulator" architecture - a clean build takes around 2.5 minutes. When I am building it for arm64 via Xcode - it takes around 15 minutes.

It seems to hang for a very long time on compiling a different seemingly random file each time. The swift-fronted process is still at 100% CPU use according to Activity Monitor.

The problem does not occur when I am building it directly via xcbuild or fastlane's gym.

I checked it on Xcode 13.2, 13.3 and 13.3.1.

I cannot find the reason for this, does anybody have a clue for why this is happening? Or maybe could point me in any direction?

Comment: You can check the different compilation logs and check if you have time consuming process.

Comment: This can also show some difference in generating for simulator and arm64. (Like signing files for arm64)